# Set base url in configuration

Tags: silverstripe

How is it possible to set the base url?

In the documentation of 3.1 is written: Director::setBaseURL: Use Director.alternate_base_url instead

Is there any example where to put the Director.alternate_base_url?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to do this is by updating your `_config.yml`, adding the following lines (remember indentations are 2 spaces):

```
Director:
  alternate_base_url: '/'
```

a full `_config.yml` file could look something like

```
---
Name: mysite
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---
SSViewer:
  theme: 'customTheme'
Director:
  environment_type: 'live'
  alternate_base_url: '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following string in your project _config.php file

```
Config::inst()->update( 'Director', 'alternate_base_url', '/' );
```

Comment: It is worth noting that Director::config() seems to generate a "method not found" error, If you need to set Director's config using Config::inst