# Where does the $BaseHref value come from in SilverStripe?

Tags: templates, url, global-variables, silverstripe

I can use {$BaseHref} in templates, but it is set to use the live website address when I'm using my dev copy of the site. I've done a flush=all. Where does it come from, so I can change it?

Edit: Sorry! I discovered I still had a hard-coded URL in my template. However, it sounds like the $BaseHref value became deprecated in SilverStripe 3.0. What should I be using instead?

Comment: The Base URL is usually set dynamically wherever your site is located. If it's not working automatically in the root `.htaccess` file check the `RewriteBase`. On a live site this will usually be set to `RewriteBase /`. On your localhost you may want it set to `RewriteBase /site-folder-name`. Otherwise check this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109864/set-base-url-in-configuration

Comment: Which version of Silverstripe are you using? The `$BaseHref` was deprecated in 3.0.

Are your live site or the dev site running in subfolders?

Comment: @wmk, 3.1.something. Can you tell me what it should be instead? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an old / updated template ? Why do you use it?

Comment: I use $absoluteBaseURL. Did you download /silverstripe-cache/ that it outputs the value from live environment?

Comment: yup, seems to be a caching problem, as it's normally dynamically calculated. @HighlyIrregular, did you do a `?flush=1` ??

Comment: @wmk, I just used it because I googled an example using it. I'm fairly new to SilverStripe, so didn't know what else to use, and didn't realise it's deprecated either. Yes I did flush, using ?flush=all. Should I be using $absoluteBaseURL instead, or something else?

Comment: @wmk Have just edited the question with new info. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I said above use $absoluteBaseURL!

Comment: @munomono, thanks... the way you said it, it wasn't entirely clear whether it was just an option you chose to use, or whether it's what I should be using. I'll google it to learn more about it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions should be answered, although it already is in comments. This answer is for the statistic :-) It's generated dynamically but is deprecated. You should use $absoluteBaseURL and this is generated here:

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/control/Director.php#L768

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/control/Director.php#L554

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/core/Constants.php#L165